# Clickable TextView inside a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, textview, clickable

I have a GridView in android and i am populating it with TextView created inside the overrided method getView of BaseAdapter class. Initially the onClick method of the created TextView is not implemented, but performs the sense of pressed. But when i implement the onClick of the TextView, it does the onClick actions, but the sense of pressed is gone.

Is there a way that i can have the sense of a pressed TextView work even with the method onClick implemented?

Thanks

Updating
hi people, the return false didn't work it shows compilation error. What i am trying to do is somiething like this: Inside the BaseAdapter to populate the GridView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView v;
    if(convertView == null){
      v = new TextView();
    }else{ 
        v = (TextView) convertView;
    }
}
```

At this point the TextView can be focused and has the sense of clicked view.
But if i implement the onClickListener like that, i can perform the action but the sense of pressed view (or focused) is gone:

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              deleteHour(mapDays.get(day));
           }
        });
```

I can see that there is an onClick event in GridView and another one in TextView. I think that when i implement the onClick method in the TextView it disables the onClick in GridView.

Maybe the question is, how to make a TextView clickable changing the state of the TextView when it is clicked? Have you got any ideas?

Thanks a lot for the replies!

Comment: Do you mean that you want the textview to still have focus?

Comment: I don't get the popint, but maybe you only have to return false at the end of the onClickListener? This is supposed to enable execution of other Listeners

Comment: yes, i want the textview to still have focus! That´s right @Zack! @2red13 I´ll try to return false at the end of the onClickListener()! If it works i come back here to tell you! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

i did it!

The way that i found is to override the setOnItemClickListener of the GridView like this:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
}
```

I hope this helps anyone with the same problem!

Thanks!